# Hide widgets with animation when I press something

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I want to add an animation to hide a widget and move/sync other widgets without it on a page.

I made an app, which is a minecraft launcher, and I want to hide the password text field when I close the switch. I made some progress on it but I couldn't add animation to make it more smooth.

Here is my code;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'forget_password_text.dart';
import 'password_text_field.dart';
import 'premium_mode_switch.dart';

class FrontLayerLeftSidePasswordHiding extends StatefulWidget {
  const FrontLayerLeftSidePasswordHiding({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FrontLayerLeftSidePasswordHidingState createState() =>
      _FrontLayerLeftSidePasswordHidingState();
}

class _FrontLayerLeftSidePasswordHidingState
    extends State<FrontLayerLeftSidePasswordHiding> {
  bool _visible = true;
  Widget? _switch;

  @override
  void initState() {
    this._switch = PremiumModeSwitch(
      onChanged: () {
        setState(() {
          this._visible = !this._visible;
        });
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This is working but, it's instant, the duration does not affect.
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
      child: _visible ? this._on() : this._off(),
    );
  }

  // This widget shows when I close the switch
  Widget _off() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Spacer(flex: 1),
        this._switcher(),
        Spacer(flex: 14),
      ],
    );
  }

  // This widget shows when I open the switch
  Widget _on() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 15,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Spacer(flex: 5),
              Expanded(
                flex: 10,
                child: PasswordTextField(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 10,
          child: this._switcher(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _switcher() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Spacer(flex: 13),
        Expanded(
          flex: 10,
          child: ForgetPasswordText(),
        ),
        Spacer(flex: 20),
        Expanded(
          flex: 10,
          child: this._switch!,
        ),
        Spacer(flex: 10),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J27Pc.gif)

Comment: You can wrap with AnimatedOpacity, hope it will work, but the widget will take spaces, in this case you can wrap again with Visibility widget and change state on animation end.

Comment: It's quite working but not like sliding animation. I want to combine slide and fade animation to make it more natural.

Comment: I recommend trying out [AnimatedContainer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html). I think you are on the right track though with your current implementation.